# uninstall shopify app any callback or setting

Tags: php, shopify

I have create a shopify app but when user delete that app in his store then can we call back any api so that we could delete his  data?

Comment: I would say most likely not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a webhook that you can listen for called `app/uninstalled`.

This fires when an app is uninstalled and you can delete the store data in your database.

Refer to the docs here: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook?api[version]=2020-04